# How to bias an AC input composite video signal

Tags: bias, video

This is a question about biasing 0V-referenced AC input signals to a positive single-ended signal. Even if the best solution for my question would be something else (and I'd like to hear about that, too,) I'd still mainly like to learn about the biasing question.

I have searched all the "biasing analog video signal" posts in here, as well as googled datasheets, and I haven't actually found one that answers the questions I ask here. Just searching the titles of other posts is misleading, because they have other requirements (using other devices, different power supplies, etc.) The suggested duplicate question "AC-Coupling on Composite video" talks about re-processing the signal, which I explicitly do NOT want to do.

## Question Background

I have a remote operated robot with a video camera generating a composite video signal going into a transmitter.

I'd now like to switch the transmitter between two separate cameras. I don't need genlock (synchronized pictures); I'm OK with the "glitch" that happens when switching between unsynchronized signals.

Weight is important, and sticking to the current design of the control systems of the robot is important.

I have looked at dedicated "video switching" ICs. The older ones, like MAX4566 and NJM2595, are generally bipolar, and require dual power supplies (+/- 3-12V.) I only have a single end power supply (5V) and ground easily available. (The video signal, generated by the camera(s), is referenced the the ground I have available.) The newer "video switching" ICs (like the TS3V330) are all for digital video differential signals (HDMI etc.) They do not work with input signals less than 0V.

A simple SPDT switching IC like the SN74LVC1G3157 is readily available, but it has protection diodes from input signal to ground and to VCC. This means that the negative half of the input signal swing will be clamped by the diode to ground. (once the diode voltage drop of 0.3V or so has been overcome)

## Actual Question

The AC signal centered around 0V is generated by an output stage in the camera (or other video equipment) like this:

[image: 75 Ohm video output]

The input to the transmitter, and other video processing devices, looks something like this:

[image: 75 Ohm video input]

(Illustrations shamelessly "borrowed" from the MinimOSD open source project schematics.)

I would like to take two of these video signals in, and switch between them (without any specific sync requirements) into one output signal, which is forwarded to the transmitter input.

I would like to not re-buffer and re-amplify the video signal. I could do that with an opamp with sufficient bandwidth, but that adds more parts and complexity. Call me lazy if you want!

So, my question is: Can I switch this signal by biasing it using a simple resistor ladder, then switching it, then adding an output capacitor?
If so, what should the values for that ladder be?
What will happen to the 75 Ohm output impedance seen by the original transmitter, and the eventual receiver?

Example:

[image: example center biased input]

(If the output from the camera doesn't actually use an isolating capacitor, I'm in trouble, though.)

Am I missing something else here, or would this "work" with reasonable signal quality?

Comment: So you want to take a composite (NTSC?) video signal of about 1volt PP with bandwidth of about 4--6MHz, of unknown DC component, with Rsource and Rload of 75 ohms..... and do what?

Comment: I want to switch between two such input signals, and forward it to an output device. I don't need to amplify or modulate the signal in any way. Like, a relay would work, if it wasn't so big and heavy, and was OK with a 6 MHz bandwidth signal.

Comment: As I understand it, the question is about providing a DC offset to AC coupled signals in order to get them through an analog switch.  Such [analog switches](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4053B.pdf) usually only pass signals that lie between the supply voltages.  If you only have ground and a positive supply, then the negative part of an AC coupled signal will be chopped off.  This is a **different** problem than restoring the DC to get proper sync detection - although it is possible the same solution would apply.

Comment: [This TI datasheet shows that a composite signal with proper DC level will still contain negative values in the signal.](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/opa615)  Nominated for reopening.

Comment: Thanks JRE, that is exactly the crux of my question, and why I feel that the "duplicate" vote didn't understand the question (or the previous answer.)